# Is there a way to revert svn property changes for a file without reverting changes to the file's contents?

Tags: svn

After a merge, I might have both content-changes as well as property-changes to a file:

> >svn st foo.h
>
> MM      foo.h

Is there a way to keep the content-changes, but revert the property-changes?

I could copy the file to a temporary location, revert, then copy back:

> >cp foo.h /tmp
>
> >svn revert foo.h
>
> >mv -f /tmp/foo.h foo.h
>
> >svn st foo.h
>
> M       foo.h

But that would be cumbersome with many files, without writing a separate script.

I was hoping there may be an svn option that I've missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I don't know of any way to just revert properties… But if I was faced with that situation, I think I would run:

```
$ svn proplist -v -r $REV foo.h
... # output, which I would copy to the clipboard
$ svn propedit foo.h
... paste in properties ...
```

And that could probably even be scripted, if you had to revert the properties for a bunch of files.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this situation myself this morning. Here's a  bash script that does the trick ...

```
for f in $( svn st . | grep '^MM' | cut -c 3- )
do 
   cp $f $f.$$ && svn revert $f && mv $f.$$ $f 
done
```

Comment: Good idea, but this script won't work with files that have spaces (or other IFS characters).